# Why does running a hundred async tasks take longer than running a hundred threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

Why does running a hundred async tasks take longer than running a hundred threads?

I have the following test class:

```
public class AsyncTests
{

    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var task = new Task(Action);
            tasks.Add(task);
            task.Start();
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());            
    }


    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        var threads = new List<Thread>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(Action);
            threads.Add(thread);
            thread.Start();
        }

        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }
    }

    private void Action()
    {
        var task1 = LongRunningOperationAsync();
        var task2 = LongRunningOperationAsync();
        var task3 = LongRunningOperationAsync();
        var task4 = LongRunningOperationAsync();
        var task5 = LongRunningOperationAsync();

        Task[] tasks = {task1, task2, task3, task4, task5};
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }

    public async Task<int> LongRunningOperationAsync()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        await Task.Delay(500);

        Debug.WriteLine("Completed at {0}, took {1}ms", DateTime.Now, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

        return 1;
    }
}
```

As far as can tell, `TestMethod1` and `TestMethod2` should do exactly the same. One uses TPL, two uses plain vanilla threads. One takes 1:30 minutes, two takes 0.54 seconds.

Why?

Comment: [Click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) - ***queuing** tasks onto threads*. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9688325/1997232) question too.

Comment: Do note that *a new Task doesn't always mean a new thread.*  `async` and `await` will often sign on tasks as *continuations* of the existing thread.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Action` method is currently blocking with the use of `Task.WaitAll(tasks)`. When using `Task` by default the `ThreadPool` will be used to execute, this means you are blocking the shared `ThreadPool` threads.

Try the following and you will see equivalent performance:

1. Add a non-blocking implementation of `Action`, we will call it `ActionAsync`

   ```
   private Task ActionAsync()
   {
       var task1 = LongRunningOperationAsync();
       var task2 = LongRunningOperationAsync();
       var task3 = LongRunningOperationAsync();
       var task4 = LongRunningOperationAsync();
       var task5 = LongRunningOperationAsync();

       Task[] tasks = {task1, task2, task3, task4, task5};
       return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
   }
   ```
2. Modify `TestMethod1` to properly handle the new `Task` returning `ActionAsync` method

   ```
   public void TestMethod1()
   {
       var tasks = new List<Task>();

       for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
       {
           tasks.Add(Task.Run(new Func<Task>(ActionAsync)));
       }

       Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());            
   }
   ```

The reason you were having slow performance is because the `ThreadPool` will "slowly" spawn new threads if required, if you are blocking the few threads it has available, you will encounter a noticeable slowdown. This is why the `ThreadPool` is only intended for running short tasks.

If you are intending to run a long blocking operation using `Task` then be sure to use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` when creating your `Task` instance (this will create a new underlying `Thread` rather than using the `ThreadPool`).

Some further evidence of the `ThreadPool` being the issue, the following also alleviates your issue (do NOT use this):

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 500);
```

This demonstrates that the "slow" spawning of new `ThreadPool` threads was causing your bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It partially answers my questions. I am still very puzzled though. Why is my code blocking and yours not? They both require the same number of threads don't they? Your code still blocks on Task.WaitAll in TestMethod1. I am still a bit lost

Comment: Also, I had to edit my post. My original version of method1 takes 1:30 minutes not 1.3 seconds.

Comment: `TestMethod1` is only called once and blocking the main thread, the issue comes in `Action` where many threads are being blocked, my implementation `ActionAsync` does not have this blocking as it is using `Task.WhenAll` which does not block. 

My implementation most likely uses less threads as it is able to re-use the `ThreadPool` threads as they are no longer blocked.

Comment: I think I see the difference now. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: You said "don't use this" in the SetMinThreads part, but what is the right way to do this then? Just start my own threads and not use the threadpool?

Answer (score 1):

Tasks are executed on threads from the threadpool. The threadpool as a limited number of threads which are reused. All task, or all requested actions, are queued and executed by those threads when they are idle.

Let's assume your threadpool has 10 threads, and you have 100 tasks waiting, then 10 tasks are executed while the other 90 tasks are simply waiting in the queue untill the first 10 tasks are finished.

In the second testmethod you create 100 threads who are dedicated to their tasks. So instead of 10 threads running simultaniously, 100 threads are doing the work.

Comment: ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads returns a 1000 threads so as far as I know there should be no difference. Furthermore your explanation still doesn't explain why testmethod1 takes 1:30 minutes