# Correct way to build asynchronously operation contract using a Task in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous

I am building a WCF service that accepts large chunks of data (usually 4MB) POST from HTTP clients, the operation contract is a function has a Stream type parameter, like this:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadData", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
void UploadData(Stream stream);
```

Since UploadData will be run by an I/O completion thread and I know processing of data could take a while, generally I should return it to I/O completion thread pool as soon as possible otherwise the concurrency will be impacted, so I plan to start a Task to copy the stream to a MemoryStream and do the following data processing from there. 
What makes me confused is, since WCF creates and maintains the stream object, after Task.Run returns, UploadData exits, WCF thinks this request has been serviced, but actually I just start to copy the stream into a MemoryStream, how can I ensure the stream object is still alive and not being disposed by WCF before copying is done?

```
public void UploadData(Stream stream)
{
    Stream incomingStream = stream; // is variable capture necessary here?
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (incomingStream)
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            }

            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // process data
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I can do stream copy before Task kicks off but that looks not clean and actually doesn't answer my confusion.

My second question is, if I use Task inside operation contract, should I keep the signature of operation contract sync or async? What is the benefit if I change operation contract to:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadData", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Task UploadDataAsync(Stream stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

at first: you don't need `Stream incomingStream = stream;`.

i have a same service and at first i implemented it just like you. i assure you stream doesn't disposed by WCF before copying or any kind of process be done. but there is another problem. you might get the out of thread exception.(you can read more about `Task.Run` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688325/when-using-task-what-happens-if-the-threadpool-is-full-busy).). so i make my service sync but i call it async. this way i could achieve the maximum performance.